# How can I get select messages ciphers for salsa20poly1305 for unit tests?

Tags: encryption, authentication, salsa20, poly1305, test-vectors

In order to avoid memory errors, I always write safe C++ wrappers with strong type-safety for any C encryption library I use.

To test my wrapper of `crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305` of libsodium and make sure I'm using it correctly, I need a set of messages, nonces and keys that someone used and encrypted and the outcome of that. This is necessary for unit tests.

In OpenSSL, when I do that, [I usually use the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031863/how-can-i-create-openssl-output-that-compares-to-openssl-c-output-to-generate), and pipe from the terminal to my unit tests and compare the output of my result.

There doesn't seem to be a terminal tool for libsodium. So I'm hoping there's either an online service that does this (take msg + nonce + key and produce cipher + mac), or someone here could provide a few test
messages and their expected mac + cipher in hex.

Comment: Try the [NaCl validation paper](https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf) or the tests/ directory in the [NaCl distribution](https://hyperelliptic.org/nacl/nacl-20110221.tar.bz2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the test vector specified by DJB himself, specified [here](https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf), chapter 4 (just XSalsa20) and chapter 10 for the box. This will already test all your primitives.

To perform boundary tests, I would strongly suggest you first document the boundaries. These are the places where there is a difference in e.g. buffer handling for the MAC function. If you test those boundaries against your own library then the MAC will still generate the same *wrong* value.

There seems to be [TweetNaCl.js](https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/secretbox) available online, so you can generate your own vectors after establishing your boundaries.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92835/discussion-on-answer-by-maarten-bodewes-how-can-i-get-select-messages-ciphers-fo).